# How do I run the same linux command in more than one tab/shell simultaneously?

Tags: shell, terminal, parallelism

Is there any tool/command in Linux that I can use to run a command in more than one tab simultaneously? I want to run the same command: `./myprog argument1 argument2` simultaneously in more than one shell to check if the mutexes are working fine in a threaded program. I want to be able to increase the number of instances of this program so as to put my code under stress later on.

I am kind of looking for something like what wall does. I can think of using tty's, but that just seems like a lot of pain if I have to scale this to many more shells.

Comment: "Any time you find yourself doing a repetitive task that involves a computer, automate it" — _me_. I think you may be doing yourself a disservice by using multiple terminal tabs for load testing because you'd have to watch them all which is tedious. Better to have one program which spawns child `myprog` instances and aggregates their output for you.

Comment: Normal multi-threading isn't going to have a mutex between processes...?

Comment: @msw: Yeah but what if I wanted to see what the end user would see when he ran the same command from his terminal and when I scaled that to say 100, what would they see on their screen? Isn't that a valid thing to determine?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: I want to check the mutexes I have put in, in the user space.

Comment: So run 99 instances under one supervisor and run a 100th in a terminal. I concede that you might be able to watch 100 terminals simultaneously, if so, I'm impressed.

Comment: Possible this might be overkill for your case. But if you really want to do a high concurrency test, Tsung might be very useful for you: http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/

Comment: Go [tmux] (http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @msw: We aim to impress. ;-) And my company is generous enough to provide me with as many monitors as I can stuff into my cubicle. :-p

Comment: Arpith, are you still looking for a solution? If not, you might want to accept one of the answers provided.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As mavillan already suggested, just use [terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html). It allows to display many terminals in a tiled way. When enabling the broadcasting feature by clicking on the grid icon (top-left) and choosing "Broadcast All", you can enter the very same command simultaneously on each terminal.

Here is an example with the date command broadcasted to a grid of 32 terminals.

[image: terminatorx32]

Comment: Damn this is awesome!

Comment: How can I easily open 32 terminals?

Comment: @Annan Terminator supports custom layouts, have a look to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168445/2594 and http://askubuntu.com/a/178242/18306

Comment: I ran into the problem, that my keystrokes were mutliple on some terminales when I broadcasted. The problem is discussed here https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/862/terminator-terminal-inserting-each-character-twice-double-broadcast-multiple-windows.
You can fix it by simply killing the ibus process with pkill ibus e.g.

Answer (score 27):

[tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) has this capability. (along with many other useful capabilities in the same vein)

Can be done via:

```
:setw synchronize-panes on
```

Comment: could you please shortly describe how tmux does that - or paste a link? thx!

Comment: :setw synchronize-panes on

Answer (score 12):

It can be achieved using iTerm2

Reference: http://korishev.com/blog/2014/02/28/iterm2-broadcast-input/

[image]

Comment: Not Linux related, since iTerm is Mac OS only and the the question is clearly asking about a Linux solution.

Answer (score 10):

#### Multixterm

Another tool to add to the list is one called [`multixterm`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/multixterm.man.html). It uses `xterm` terminals. You can invoke it like so:

```
$ multixterm
```

And once up you'll be presented with a GUI.

[image: ss of gui]

You can then start spinning up `xterm` windows by clicking the `new xterm` button. Here for example I've invoked 2. If you then click on the primary window, you can start typing commands in both windows simultaneously:

[image: ss of xtems]

#### keyboardcast

Appears to only be available on Ubuntu, looks similar to multixterm.

*excerpt*

> The purpose of keyboardcast is to allow you to send keystrokes to multiple
>   X windows at once. This allows you, for example, to control a number of
>   terminals connected to different but similar hosts for purposes of mass-
>   administration.
>
> You can also select non-terminals. If you come up with a reasonable use
>   for this ability I'd be interested in hearing about it.
>
> The program can select windows to send to either by matching their titles
>   (using a substring) or by clicking on them (in a method similar to GIMP's
>   screenshot feature).
>
> The program also features the ability to spawn off multiple instances of
>   gnome-terminal executing a single command on multiple arguments (for example
>   executing 'ssh' on several hosts). The gnome-terminals are invoked with
>   the profile 'keyboardcast' if it exists (so, for example, your font size
>   can be smaller).

- [Control Multiple Terminals Simultaneously](http://www.frozenindustries.com/2006/09/21/control-multiple-terminals-simultaneously/)
- [keyboardcast on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/keyboardcast)

Comment: keepers! Note taken.

Comment: It seems that keyboardcast is broken, which is disappointing.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a KDE user, with konsole 2.13.2 on KDE 4.13.3 you can do this:

1. open konsole
2. split view vertically
   [image]
3. write simultaneously on each terminal inside the window
   [image]

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like:

```
max_processes=20
for ((i=0; i<$max_processes; i++))
do 
    /path/to/myprog arg1 arg2 > /tmp/myprog.${i}.log &
done
```

Or if the output of each command is relevant during execution, you can setup screen.

```
vi ~/.screenrc
screen -t inst1    1 /path/to/myprog arg1 arg2
screen -t inst2    2 /path/to/myprog arg1 arg2
screen -t inst3    3 /path/to/myprog arg1 arg2
screen -t inst4    4 /path/to/myprog arg1 arg2
```

The screen requires more manual work.

Comment: Could you expand more on the screen solution? More in line with what I want...

Comment: why not just `tail -f` the log file instead of setting up a hundred screens.

Comment: @Arpith the screen spawn several terminals in a single one. If you want to see all of them in "real time" then you can use screen. Although personally I would go with logfiles, you can set up your prog to send a message or actually have your own prog writing a logfile for each instance (ex: myprog.pid.log)

Comment: @LieRyan because unless you're logging with something like syslog you have to log to a separate file for each process. If you simply try to have 20+ processes write to the same file at the same time you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Sammitch: `tail -f *.log`

Answer (score 5):

Try Terminator (emulator terminal). It can have many shell sessions in the same window and you can broadcast a command to all of them.

[Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a tool like MobaXterm and it will allow you to connect simultaneously and then paste your commands into all of your windows.

Comment: Not Linux related, as mobaxterm, whike very impressive for what it does, is Windows only and the question is clearly about a Linux solution.

Comment: @R J They could all be ssh terminals for a remote Linux host.  OP asked for Linux "commands", not a Linux client.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to see output from the 100th program execution:

```
#!/bin/bash

prog="/path/to/myprog"
args="argument1 argument2"
max=100
for i in $(seq $max); do
    if [ $i -lt $max ]; then
        exec $prog $args &> /dev/null &
    else
        exec $prog $args
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can control `konsole` through `DCOP`. An example is [from here](http://www.revragnarok.com/blog/blog/konsole_tabs):

```
#!/bin/bash

checkfile() {
  if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo "could not find $1"
    exit 99
  else
    echo "OK"
  fi
}

# Check for App1 XML
echo -n "Checking for App 1 XML... "
XMLA=/domain/DM.xml
checkfile ${DEVROOT}/${XMLA}

# Check for App2 XML
echo -n "Checking for App 2 XML... "
hostname=$(hostname)
XMLB=/domain/DM_${hostname}.xml
checkfile ${DEVROOT}/${XMLB}

# Launch Konsole
echo -n "Launching konsole... "
K=$(dcopstart konsole-script)

[ -z "${K}" ] && exit 98
# Create second tab and resize
SDA=$(dcop $k konsole currentSession)
SDB=$(dcop $k konsole newSession)
dcop $K $SDA setSize 121x25

# Let bash login, etc.
sleep 1

# Rename the tabs
dcop $K $SDA renameSession "App 1"
dcop $K $SDB renameSession "App 2"

# Start services, letting user watch
echo -n "starting app1... "
dcop $K konsole activateSession $SDA
dcop $K $SDA sendSession "echo -ne '\033]0;DEV (${hostname})\007' && clear && starter $XMLA"
sleep 2
echo -n "starting app2... "
dcop $K konsole activateSession $SDB
dcop $K $SDB sendSession "echo -ne '\033]0;DEV (${hostname})\007' && clear && starter $XMLB"
echo done.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sh <<-STRESS & 
$( printf 'myprog &\n%.0b' \
    `seq 1 ${MAX_CONCURRENT_PROCS}` )
STRESS
echo "$!"
```

I agree with the comment @msw makes above. This will write you a script to be launched by a backgrounded `sh` process and print out the child `sh` process's pid so you can monitor it and its children as it works.

Answer (score 2):

@Jinpeng was on the right track with [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), just not the implementation.

**Example: Run 10 parallel instances of your program, with each thread running your program only once:**

```
parallel -j10 './myprog argument1 argument2 #' ::: {1..10}
```

**Example: Run 10 parallel threads, with each of those threads running your program infinitely:**

```
parallel -j10 'while true ; do ./myprog argument1 argument2 ; done #' ::: {1..10}
```

You can easily scale this to the hundreds of threads by replacing the `10` in my examples.

```
parallel -j200     ...     ::: {1..200}
```

If your program produces any stdout messages and you want to see them as they are produced (rather than the default which collates them), the `--ungroup` option to parallel may be useful.

```
parallel --ungroup   ...
```

If you are running a lot of threads from your workstation and don't want things to become unresponsive, consider `nice`ing the whole process subtree at launch time.

```
nice -n19 parallel   ...
```

Side note, GNU Parallel is usually not installed by default but is usually in your normal package repos, so just install it like any other package: `dnf install parallel`, `apt-get install parallel`, `brew install parallel`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can start processes in the background with [`nohup`](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/nohup).

Example:

```
nohup ./myprog -arg1 -arg2 &
```

Output:

```
[1] 1769    
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

Remember to kill the task later with the given `PID`:

```
kill 1769
```

To bring the process in the foreground you must enter the jobnumber, in this case `[1]`:

```
fg %1
```

Answer (score 1):

gnu parallel is exactly the tool you are looking for.
`parallel -j 9 yourcommand`

Answer (score 0):

My little to mill:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -lt 1 ] && {
        echo "Use: $0 <file>
        where file includes list of server"
        exit 9
}

cp ~/.config/terminator/config ~/.config/terminator/config.`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`

cat ~/.config/terminator/config.`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`|grep -v "^.plugins" >~/.config/terminator/config

inc=5
echo "  [[terms]]" >>~/.config/terminator/config
for i in `cat $1` ; do
        echo "   [[[window${inc}]]]"
        echo "       type = Window"
        echo "   [[[terminal${inc}]]]"
        echo "     profile = default"
        echo "     order = 0" 
        echo "     type = Terminal"
        echo "     parent = window${inc}"
        echo "     command = ssh $i"
        inc=$((inc+1))
done >>~/.config/terminator/config

echo "[plugins]" >>~/.config/terminator/config
```

Will make terminator config (layout terms) for many windows in one group.

EDIT: At least, terminator is able to send broadcast into every terminal in same group. This function is switchable - so you may enable it write 'su -' then disable and write owen password to onces terminals and enable it again.

Comment: Is it better? Excuse me unwell English please :)