# How to open terminal, split to 9 terminals and switch between them using one script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, perl, gnome-terminator

I would like to open a terminal, split it to lets say 9 parts (3x3) and execute some bash script. But for each terminal part different script.

Can this be done using perl, python or even bash?

How can I switch between those little terminals without using keyboard shortcuts?

Oh, by the way, I'm using `terminator`. And if there is some other terminal emulator that enables such a functionality, which is it?

Comment: `terminator` is not a shell. There are two different _terminal emulators_ called `terminator` (only one of which I believe can split the screen).

Comment: Ah, thanks .. then I'd like to know how to split `terminator` using script? :) And switch between those parts?

Comment: I've never used it and don't have the time to research it right now, but I think (not sure though) that byobu could help you if you're running the terminals on a remote system -- see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu. Byobu runs on many *nix distributions

Comment: As @ClivevanHilten mention and [answered here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355145/209677) it can be done with friendly Byobu (which by default sit on top of tmux).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[To plagiarize myself](https://superuser.com/a/610048/151431), you can set up a profile with your desired settings (instructions adapted from [here](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html)):

1. Run `terminator` and set up the layout you want. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to split windows vertically and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (that's O as in oodles, not zero) to split horizontally. For this example, I have created a layout with 6 panes:

   [image]
2. Right click on the `terminator` window and choose *Preferences*. Once the *Preferences* window is open, go to *Layouts* and click *Add*:

   [image]
3. That will populate the *Layouts* list with your new layout:

   [image]
4. Find each of the terminals you have created in the layout and click on them. Then on the right, enter the command you want to run in them on startup:

   [image]

   **IMPORTANT:** Note that the command is followed by `; bash`. If you don't do that, the terminals will not be accessible, since they will run the command you give and exit. You need to launch a shell after each command to be able to use the terminals.

   Once you have set all the commands, click *Close* and then exit `terminator`.
5. Open the `terminator` config file `~/.config/terminator/config` and delete the section under layouts for the default config. Then change the name of the layout you created to default. It should look something like this:

   ```
    [global_config]
    [keybindings]
    [profiles]
      [[default]]
    [layouts]
      [[default]]
        [[[child0]]]
          position = 446:100
          type = Window
          order = 0
          parent = ""
          size = 885, 550
        [[[child1]]]
          position = 444
          type = HPaned
          order = 0
          parent = child0
        [[[child2]]]
          position = 275
          type = VPaned
          order = 0
          parent = child1
        [[[child5]]]
          position = 219
          type = HPaned
          order = 1
          parent = child1
        [[[child6]]]
          position = 275
          type = VPaned
          order = 0
          parent = child5
        [[[child9]]]
          position = 275
          type = VPaned
          order = 1
          parent = child5
        [[[terminal11]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'df -h; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 1
          parent = child9
        [[[terminal10]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'export foo="bar" && cd /var/www/; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 0
          parent = child9
        [[[terminal3]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'ssh -Yp 24222 cchapple@139.124.66.43'
          type = Terminal
          order = 0
          parent = child2
        [[[terminal4]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'top; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 1
          parent = child2
        [[[terminal7]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'cd /etc; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 0
          parent = child6
        [[[terminal8]]]
          profile = default
          command = 'cd ~/dev; bash'
          type = Terminal
          order = 1
          parent = child6
    [plugins]
   ```

The final result is that when you run `terminator` it will open with 6 panes, each of which has run or is running the commands you have specified:

[image]

Also, you can set up as many different profiles as you wish and either launch terminator with the `-p` switch giving a profile name, or manually switch to whichever profile you want after launching.

Comment: Terdon, thank you! This is probably where I learned to write that config file!

Comment: @dotancohen glad to hear I was of help :)

Comment: Whaou! Great thanks, the "; bash" saved my life !

Comment: "You need to launch a shell after each command to be able to use the terminals." Amazing - this was not intuitive at all when I initially tried it. They should include some kind of checkbox to automatically enable this.

Answer (score 6):

Are you searching for terminal multiplexer tmux.

https://github.com/tmux/tmux

Comment: Yes, this seems as another possibility how to accomplish what I need to. Thanks :)

Comment: `tmux` is excellent!

Answer (score 4):

Back when I was using `terminator` this is the rc file that I used to open a bunch of terminals and run applications. Save it to `.config/terminator/config`.

```
[global_config]
  title_hide_sizetext = True
  enabled_plugins = LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
[keybindings]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    font = DejaVu Sans Mono 9
    cursor_blink = False
    scrollback_infinite = True
[layouts]
  [[default]]

    [[[root]]]
      position = -4:0
      type = Window
      order = 0 
      parent = ""
      size = 1072, 1884

    [[[grand]]]
      position = 536 
      type = HPaned
      order = 0 
      parent = root
    [[[left]]]
      position = 942 
      type = VPaned
      order = 0 
      parent = grand
    [[[right]]]
      position = 942 
      type = VPaned
      order = 1 
      parent = grand



    [[[terminal1]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0 
      parent = left
      command = "cd ~/code/foo; bash"
    [[[terminal2]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1 
      parent = left
      command = "cd ~/bar/baz; bash"



    [[[terminal3]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1 
      parent = right
      command = ""
    [[[terminal4]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0 
      parent = right
      command = "cmus; bash"



[plugins]
```

**EDIT:** Note that this information probably came from Terdon's post on a much earlier thread. I've been using this setup for a few months, but Terdon's post here looks very familiar!

Comment: This is what I was looking for - how to split terminal & execute particular scripts - thanks! But I wouldn't like to execute it everytime like this. Is there a possibility to have more of those configs & open each depending on what I need? Let's say by adding parameter --config2 or --config1 ?

Comment: You don't add more config files, you add sections to the config file. See Terdon's post, he explains it very well, in fact I learned this from his post on an earlier thread.

Comment: Oh, I see ... Thus I accepted his answer as most helpful. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Good choice! I actually wanted to suggest to accept his answer as the information did come from his hard work!

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper script for splitting Terminator terminal emulator
https://github.com/AlekseyChudov/terminator-split

Comment: You should include the relevant information here, once github is gone your answer loses all of its potential value.

Comment: seems good.. but how do I run this script?

Comment: `terminator-split` has a lot of potential, but there seems to be no way to run different commands in the different splits, and the `-m` argument shown in the examples is not listed in the usage summary