# Linux Mint Infrastructure Management

Tags: debian, linux-mint, ansible

I want to deploy Linux Mint on ~40 PCs.

If I do that, I will need a centralized way to control those PCs.

For Example,

1. install/remove software on all those PCs on the same time,
2. set environment variables on all those PCs on the same time,
3. Change wallpaper on all those PCs on the same time, ETC.

I did some research. The references are -

[Group policy with Linux servers?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/492068-group-policy-with-linux-servers)

[How to manage enterprise network of Linux machines?](https://serverfault.com/questions/434197/how-to-manage-enterprise-network-of-linux-machines)

[Deploying software to multiple ubuntu clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/381613/deploying-software-to-multiple-ubuntu-clients)

[user policies on Ubuntu Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/851820/user-policies-on-ubuntu-server)

And found that the solutions include Spacewalk, landscape, chef and puppet.

**Please let me know if I missed something during my research.** Being said that, I am interested to use Ansible which was not recommended in the forums I visited. **Will Ansible perform tasks 1, 2, and 3?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269617/linux-equivalent-to-powershells-one-to-many-remoting/269626#269626

Comment: In addition to the link above take a look at the code frequency of [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/graphs/code-frequency), [Puppet](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/graphs/code-frequency), [Chef](https://github.com/chef/chef/graphs/code-frequency) and [Salt](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/graphs/code-frequency). Then take a look at the list of [Ansible modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_all_modules.html). Then take a look at [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/), [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx) ...

Comment: @K7AAY please [don’t edit closed questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5319/86440) unless it’s to fix the problems which caused them to be closed.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: Thought I was taking care of the problem which led to closure.

Comment: @K7AAY there’s still the “etc.” on task 3, and “Please let me know if I missed something during my research”... (But mainly I wanted to make sure you were aware of the impact of edits on closed questions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works) will perform the three tasks you outlined above, and provides [multiple examples](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works) of how to configure their [playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html) of actions you can apply to all devices, or selectively based on conditions.