# check ssh-key multiple servers

Tags: shell-script, ssh, rhel, python

I need to make a script to check authentication of an user with ssh-key on multiple Redhat servers, approximately 980 servers.

User can edit script for userID and private ssh-key location.

Script must:

- check successful login or failed(if asked for password) and output into log file;
- read servers IP's/hostnames from servers.txt;
- skip if server is offline.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: For that volume of machines I strongly recommend investing on using a more automation oriented tool than bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux equivalent to PowerShell's "one-to-many" remoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269617/linux-equivalent-to-powershells-one-to-many-remoting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# I assume "logfile" is the log file. If you just want the last run 
# in the log fil, use date> logfile.
# It is always a good idea to get a time stamp in this kind of logs.
date >> logfile 

# The read takes the input from servers.txt, which is done at the
# bottom using `done < servers.txt`.
# Some people like to do `cat servers.txt | while read -r hostname ; do`
# but they get negative comments on stackexchange :-)
while read -r hostname ; do

    # Test if the host is up with a simple ping
    # Throw away all output.
    if ping -c1 "$hostname"  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null; then

        # We now test if a host is up with a simple command, echo.
        # with -o PasswordAuthentication=no, we make sure that password
        # authentication is not used. Output the result to the logfile.
        if ssh  -o PasswordAuthentication=no "$hostname" echo ' '; then
            echo "OK - $hostname" >>logfile
        else
            echo "AArrrghhh $hostname" >> logfile
        fi
    else
        # I assumed you want some idea of how many servers are skipped.
        echo "skipped $hostname" >> logfile
    fi
done < servers.txt
```

It is a quick write and it will probably need some tweaking. The comments should give you some hints on what to check.

Comment: that fixed it!! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect :-)
I did some modifications to it ;-)

Convert private.ppk to private.pem:

```
$ apt install putty-tools
$ puttygen private.ppk -O private-openssh -o private.pem
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add priv_key.pem
```

And script will run perfect

output.log

```
root@Pi-3Plus:~# cat output.log
Sat 20 Jul 20:37:51 EEST 2019
SSH-Key Refused - 192.168.1.106
No route to 192.168.4.34
SSH-Key Accepted - 192.168.1.2
No route to 192.168.4.33
SSH-Key Refused - 192.168.1.101
SSH-Key Refused - 192.168.1.195
No route to 192.168.4.39
SSH-Key Accepted - 192.168.1.2
```

Adding modifications of code below.

```
#!/bin/bash
# I assume "logfile" is the log file. If you just want the last run
# in the log fill, use date> logfile.
# It is always a good idea to get a time stamp in this kind of logs.
date >> output.log

# The read takes the input from servers.txt, which is done at the
# bottom using `done < servers.txt`.
# Some people like to do `cat servers.txt | while read -r hostname ; do`
# but they get negative comments on stackexchange :-)
while read -r hostname ; do

    # Test if the host is up with a simple ping
    # Throw away all output.
    if ping -c1 "$hostname"  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null; then

        # We now test if a host is up with a simple command, echo.
        # with -o PasswordAuthentication=no, we make sure that password
        # authentication is not used. Output the result to the logfile.
        if ssh -l ADDUSERHERE -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o PasswordAuthentication=no -n "$hostname" echo ''; then
        echo "SSH-Key Accepted - $hostname" >>output.log
    else
        echo "SSH-Key Refused - $hostname" >> output.log
    fi
else
    # I assumed you want some idea of how many servers are skipped.
    echo "No route to $hostname" >> output.log
    fi
done < servers.txt
```